# firefox default min-width on page content?

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to create a fluid html doc that will scale down to a min-width of 350px and a max-width of 600px.  Im experience some strange behavior, seems as if firefox won't scale the content lower than around 515px.

```
    <div id="wrap" style="min-width:350px; max-width:600px; padding:0px; margin:0px;border:dashed 3px #ff0000;">    
    <div id="top" class="gradient blue-one">
        <span class="headerOne">Header 1</span>
        <span class="headerTwo">Header 2</span>
    </div>

    <div id="details">
        <div class="gradient grey-one" id="">
            <span class="valueOne">Value One</span>
            <span class="valueTwo">Value Two</span>
        </div>
        <div class="gradient grey-one" id="">
            <span class="valueOne">Value One</span>
            <span class="valueTwo">Value Two</span>
        </div>
        <div class="gradient grey-one" id="">
            <span class="valueOne">Value One</span>
            <span class="valueTwo">Value Two</span>
        </div>                                          
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log($(window).width());
    })
});

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried in FF 3.6.13 with 'min-width' and it works. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: Tried now and works for me ... I just installed v8 and I do not see any problem.

Comment: you are seeing the right side of the border at 350px?  Would you be willing to post a screenshot with the div and console output?

Comment: Here you are http://agencia.ro/aks/width.png

Comment: thanks... thats odd.  Here is a screenshot of mine: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/C5Pp6rZoHOioy0QaB1vQb9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox user interface sometimes has a bug that prevents it from resizing the browser viewport down below some minimal width.  That width will depend on your exact toolbar configuration.

The simplest way to deal with it is to put your page in an iframe and size that iframe to whatever you want.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: +1 In my testing, Firefox wouldn't shrink the page to be narrower than the Navigation toolbar.